# Range of a holomorphic function on the disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a very simple question that had driven me mad these last hours :

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function from the unit disc $\mathbb{D} =\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z| < 1\} $ to $\mathbb{C}$. Can the range of $f$ be all the complex plane ?

Comment: Is the unit disc taken as the open unit ball?

Comment: I have edited, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Certainly, $f$ cannot be a biholomorphism.

Comment: The problem happens if you add the hypothesis that $f'(z)\neq 0$ (or that $f$ is injective on the unit circle over the complex plane). In this case, there is no such function.

Comment: @GustavoMarra: I think $f'\ne 0$ is insufficient to exclude the possibility of $f(\Bbb D)=\Bbb C$. Do you mean $f'\ne 0$ and $f$ is [proper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map)?

Comment: "f'\neq 0" in every point of the unit open ball $D$ means that $f$ is injective. If $f(D)=\mathbb{C}$ (OP's hypothesis), then $f^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow D$ is holomorphic and limited on an open set, therefore, $f^{-1}$ is constant.

Comment: @GustavoMarra: No, $f'\ne 0$ on $\Bbb D$ cannot imply that $f$ is injective on $\Bbb D$. For example, consider $f(z)=(z+1)^3$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function $\sin\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, surjective and periodic of period $2\,\pi$. This implies that its restriction to the half-plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z:\Re{z}>0\}$ is also onto $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\phi\colon\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}$ be a Möebius transformation between $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{H}$. Then $\sin(\phi(z))$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and onto $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add an example without trigonometry: 
$$f(z)=\left(\frac{z }{ 1-z}\right)^2$$
Here, $z\mapsto z/(1-z)$ maps the unit disk onto the halfplane $\operatorname{Re}z>-1/2$. The image of this halfplane under $z\mapsto z^2$ is the entire plane.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it can. To see this, consider a function $f: \ ]0, 1[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose range is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. One example would be $f(x) = \tan(\pi x - \pi/2)$. Now let $g: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. For any $z \neq 0 \in \mathbb{D}$, define $g(z)$ to be the complex number with modulus $f(|z|)$ and argument the same as that of $z$. For $z = 0$, take $g(z) = 0$.

Comment: Is such a function analytic? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick. I missed that part. However, I do think it will be as it is essentially just a rescaling of the complex number $z$.